# Make menu selected on specific page Wordpress

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css, wordpress

I am new to `Wordpress`, so I don't know all possible features, I tried to find proper way but didn't get anything related.

My question is about menu. I want menu item to be selected according to specific page where user is currently on.

So taks is simple, but I don't know how to implement this better, maybe `Wordpress` engine has proper function of feature.

I can just hardcode in my header file `php` code which checks what is current `URL` and apply specific style to current div block or `javascript` code that doing the same, but this is not flexible way to implement this.

I have different options for example if current page is article or category I still need to highlight `Blog` menu item.

**SOLUTION**

I have just realized that my theme, or wordpress core applies `current-menu-item` to currently selected menu item from the box, so just added css rules and it works.

Please who knows how it decides to apply this attribute to the menu item please share.
Thanks

Comment: Could you please provide a link to your actual website project (put it in your question, updating it. Like this you can erase it afterward)?

Comment: isn't there an active line in the css already for Wordpress?

Comment: This function doesn't exist by default, you would need to hardcode it as you've described or you can also create different templates for some of your pages and use a custom header for each template thereby letting you call a unique menu for the corresponding template.